# Extract AJAX content and java scripted content using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawling this [site](http://www.freeindex.co.uk/profile(the-main-event-management-company)_266537.htm) and want to extract contact number which is inside the call button.

How can I implement this code??

Comment: can you explain why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple AJAX request is being made to retrieve html string with the phone numbers:

[image]

```
import re
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sophone'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.freeindex.co.uk/profile(the-main-event-management-company)_266537.htm'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # item id can be extracted from url
        item_id = re.findall("(\d+)\.htm", response.url)[0]
        # phone api can be made using this id
        url = 'http://www.freeindex.co.uk/customscripts' \
              '/popup_view_tel_details.asp?id={}'.format(item_id)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_phone)

    def parse_phone(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)
```